# UNNEST on GENERATE_TIMESTAMP_ARRAY() causes syntax error

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, unnest

My goal is to use an existing table with patient_id's and corresponding dates (secifically timestamps) of entry and exit at the hospital (called min_time and max_time) to **create a new table where each 4-hour bloc is a row**.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKhVF.png)

My current SQL code is as follows:

```
CREATE table new_table as(
    SELECT patient_id, 
    UNNEST(GENERATE_TIMESTAMP_ARRAY(min_time, max_time, INTERVAL 4 HOUR)) as time
    FROM parent_table
    ORDER BY patient_id, time)
```

However I get the following error: **'Syntax error: Expected ")" but got keyword UNNEST'**. I can easily create the timestamp_array so I know GENERATE_TIMESTAMP_ARRAY(min_time, max_time, INTERVAL 4 HOUR) works. I believe the issue arises because the format UNNEST(GENERATE...) is not accepted, but am unsure of a better alternative. **Any idea how to fix it?** *(Code run on BigQuery)*

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it really depends if you want an array in your final output or a "flattened" table.

For an array in your final output...

```
SELECT 
  patient_id, 
  GENERATE_TIMESTAMP_ARRAY(min_time, max_time, INTERVAL 4 HOUR) as time
FROM parent_table
ORDER BY patient_id
```

For a flattened version (which sounds like what you are shooting for)...

```
SELECT 
  patient_id, 
  time
FROM parent_table,
     UNNEST(GENERATE_TIMESTAMP_ARRAY(min_time, max_time, INTERVAL 4 HOUR)) as time
ORDER BY patient_id, time
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the attached sample data, I assume that the data type of columns `min_time` and `max_time` is `DATETIME`, hence you would need to convert these column data type to `TIMESTAMP` first to be able to use `GENERATE_TIMESTAMP_ARRAY` syntax.

Tried this on my end using this sample data:

[image]

Script:

```
CREATE TABLE `myproject.mydataset.newtable` AS (
SELECT 
    patient_id, 
    DATETIME(time) time
FROM `myproject.mydataset.mytable`,
    UNNEST(GENERATE_TIMESTAMP_ARRAY(CAST(min_time AS TIMESTAMP), CAST(max_time AS TIMESTAMP), INTERVAL 4 HOUR)) as time
ORDER BY patient_id, time
)
```

Output table:

[image]